# Laravel Custom Errors

Tags: laravel, error-handling

This is my Laravel validation. What I want to do is if input vtype =='s' I want to send an error custom error message to show in the form. How can I do That

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'date' => 'required|date|'
    ])->validate();

    if($request->input('vtype')==='s'){
        return Redirect::back();
    }
     elseif($request->input('piklocation')==='A'){
        return Redirect::back();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with flash session data, like this:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Error message');
```

then in your view:

```
@if($error)
  <p> {{ $error }} </p>
@endif
```